# Adjust table width without messing up preliminary set by paper guidelines

Tags: tables

Hi I am in the midst of publishing paper to IJNT. I downloaded the page guidelines from the corresponding website. The only problem I am having is that I could not adjust the table to fit the page margin set by IJNT. Below is the code for my table

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \def\arraystretch{3.0}
    \begin{scriptsize}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \cline{1-3}
     $\mu \in Y$ & $\mu P \oplus T'$  & $Z(nP)$ \\ \cline{1-3}
    $-4$ & $\bigg(\dfrac{4482}{361}\beta + \dfrac{3489}{361}, \dfrac{-52002}{6859}\beta + \dfrac{2057238}{6859}\bigg)$  & $2^{22}\cdot3^{44}\cdot19^{-32}\cdot \bm{13\cdot1789}\cdot[-46931113911612188165\beta + 242506871209270916181]^2$  \\ \cline{1-3}
    $-3$ & $\bigg(\dfrac{-99}{8}\beta + \dfrac{93}{8}, \dfrac{-81}{16}\beta - \dfrac{5049}{16}\bigg)$  & $2^{-32}\cdot3^{34}\cdot\bm{5\cdot29}\cdot\bigg[\dfrac{-143654012463}{2}\beta + \dfrac{596091741497}{2}\bigg]^2$  \\ \cline{1-3}
     $-2$ & $(162\beta + 681,-5994\beta - 24786)$ & $[2^{13}\cdot3^{22}\cdot5\cdot19\cdot379\cdot1433\cdot1481\beta + 2^{13}\cdot3^{23}\cdot199\cdot527732929]^2$\\ \cline{1-3}
    $-1$ & $(-18\beta + 69, -162\beta + 918)$  & $2^{24}\cdot3^{34}\cdot\bm{5\cdot29}\cdot[95293 +23052\beta]^2$  \\ \cline{1-3}
    $0$ & $\bigg(\frac{3}{2}(-5 - 9\beta),0\bigg)$  & $2^{10}\cdot 3^{44}\cdot \bm{13\cdot1789}\cdot[21\beta + 7]^2 $  \\ \cline{1-3}
    $3$ & $\bigg(\dfrac{-99}{8}\beta + \dfrac{93}{8}, \dfrac{81}{16}\beta + \dfrac{5049}{16}\bigg)$  & $2^{-32}\cdot3^{34}\cdot\bm{5333\cdot97324757}\cdot\bigg[\dfrac{2188485}{2}\beta + \dfrac{12121421}{2}\bigg]^2$  \\ \cline{1-3}
    \end{tabular}
\end{scriptsize}
    \caption{$Z(\widetilde{Q})$ a square for $\mu \in Y$.\label{znpsquare}}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way, (without messing up with their preliminaries), I can adjust this table to fit the margin. I have attach an image for the table generated.

[image]

Comment: your table is to wide. try to split equation in the second column into more line. for more help you should provide complete small document beginning with  `\documentclass{...}` ans ending with `\end{document}`. in preamble load only for page layout and table settings necessary packages.

Comment: How can we possibly know when we don't know what we are not meant to mess up? You can resize the table, of course, but this is not recommended and may violate the requirements.

Comment: I guess you need to specify the document class since otherwise i will be hard to help you. And do you really want to use `scriptsize`?

Comment: The content in your `tabular` is too wide. You need to adjust it to fit; it won't just magically happen. Possible duplicate: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/5764)

Comment: @Zarko Sorry about that.  I have edited my code and have included \documentclass{...} ans ending with \end{document}

Comment: @marmot i was playing around to make the table fit the page, this is the closest I could get, by using \scriptsize, but still does not satisfy.

Comment: Well, I guess that the journal's guidelines are there for a reason, at least that's what those who invented them believe. You can scale anything to any size with `\scalebox`, but I'm not sure that the journal allows you to do that. Therefore you might want to do something different, like replacing `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}` by `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|p{5cm}|}` or something along these lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i said in comment, your table with one line equation is to wide. reasonable solution is break equation into more line. for example with help of `multlined` from `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\usepackage{mathtools}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\makegapedcells
\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt}
\centering
\[
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
\mu \in Y & \mu P \oplus T'  
    & Z(nP) \\ 
    \hline
-4  &   \begin{multlined}
        \bigg(\dfrac{4482}{361}\beta + \dfrac{3489}{361},\\[-2ex]
        \dfrac{-52002}{6859}\beta + \dfrac{2057238}{6859}\bigg)
        \end{multlined}  
        &   \begin{multlined}
            2^{22}\cdot3^{44}\cdot19^{-32}\cdot \mathbf{13\cdot1789}    \\[-2ex]
            \cdot[-46931113911612188165\beta + \\
                242506871209270916181]^2
            \end{multlined}         \\ 
    \hline
-3  &   \begin{multlined}
        \bigg(\dfrac{-99}{8}\beta + \dfrac{93}{8}, \\[-2ex]
        \dfrac{-81}{16}\beta - \dfrac{5049}{16}\bigg)  
        \end{multlined}
        &   \begin{multlined}
            2^{-32}\cdot3^{34}\cdot\mathbf{5\cdot29}   \\[-2ex]
            \cdot\bigg[\dfrac{-143654012463}{2}\beta + \dfrac{596091741497}{2}\bigg]^2  
            \end{multlined}         \\ 
    \hline
 -2 &   \begin{multlined}
        (162\beta + 681,\\[-2ex]
        -5994\beta - 24786)
        \end{multlined}
        &   \begin{multlined}
            [2^{13}\cdot3^{22}\cdot5\cdot19\cdot379\cdot1433\cdot1481\beta +\\[-2ex] 2^{13}\cdot3^{23}\cdot199\cdot527732929]^2
            \end{multlined} \\
        \hline
-1  &   \begin{multlined}
        (-18\beta + 69, \\[-2ex]
        -162\beta + 918)  
        \end{multlined}
        &   \begin{multlined}
        2^{24}\cdot3^{34}\cdot\mathbf{5\cdot29} \\[-2ex]
            \cdot[95293 +23052\beta]^2  
            \end{multlined} \\ 
    \hline
0   &   \bigg(\frac{3}{2}(-5 - 9\beta), 0\bigg)  
        &   2^{10}\cdot 3^{44} \cdot \mathbf{13\cdot1789}\cdot[21\beta + 7]^2 
                            \\  
    \hline
3   &   \begin{multlined}
        \bigg(\dfrac{-99}{8}\beta + \dfrac{93}{8}, \\[-2ex]
        \dfrac{81}{16}\beta + \dfrac{5049}{16}\bigg)  
        \end{multlined}
        &  \begin{multlined}
            2^{-32}\cdot3^{34}\cdot\mathbf{5333\cdot97324757}\\[-2ex]
            \cdot\bigg[\dfrac{2188485}{2}\beta + \dfrac{12121421}{2}\bigg]^2
            \end{multlined} \\
    \hline
\end{array}
\]
    \caption{$Z(\widetilde{Q})$ a square for $\mu \in Y$.}
\label{znpsquare}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

in code i make some changes as:

- `tabular` is replaced by `array` which is encapsulated in math environment
- for boldface variables `\mathbf{...}` is used
- more vertical space around math expression is obtain by `\makegapedcells` from package `makecell`
  in preamble are loaded only packages needed for setting this table